# How to achieve full disk encryption on Windows Machine with User Profiles on a separate drive?

Tags: encryption, veracrypt

I'm currently struggling to find a solution to the issue- I am looking to achieve full disk encryption on a Windows 10 x64 based machine, which in itself is simple enough, however, I have the User Profiles (ProgramData, etc) folders on a separate drive D:\ and the OS is installed on my SSD which is drive C:.

Things I've Tried:
Typical Veracrypt Setup with Automount Drive D:\ (this did not work, because Windows loads the OS and throws an error when it can't locate the UserProfiles data)

Anyone got ideas or have a similar setup? Having a secondary data drive with the User Data on it is not uncommon. Must be a solution out there.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your other question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157861/what-is-the-best-way-to-encrypt-a-system-drive-while-automounting-a-secondary-dr

Comment: This is definitely a SuperUser question. And here is the answer you're looking for: Bitlocker

Comment: Bitlocker is only available on Windows 10 Pro and Enterprise, the OP hasn't specified which version of W10 he is using.